# How can I install Ethereum on the Windows 10 Ubuntu Bash

Tags: cpp-ethereum, windows, compilation

Windows 10 new preview release includes the Ubuntu Bash.

I would like to know if anybody has had some luck installing ethereum using the bash, and can provide details instructions.

`apt-get install cpp-ethereum` does not work, as it includes the qt components like mix and alethzero.

Building from source allows you to ignore the compilation of these when creating the cmake file, but it is failing linking libscrypt.so

Note: The bash is in beta at the moment, the same issue on compilation has been reported, so it might be safe to assume, at the moment, this is a bash / windows issue.

Comment: Interesting question, did you follow the Ubuntu installation documentation? Did you include the ethdev repositories?

Comment: yes, it seems to be a general issue with the windows ubuntu bash as bob summerville is having the same problem.